# Chrome WebSocket Stops Receiving

Tags: websocket

When I send

`'\x81\x04pong'`

to the websocket, it receives fine.

When I send

`'\x81\x7e\xd0\x00abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklm
nopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`

it doesn't receive, nor does it receive any further frames.

I think the problem might be in the second, third or fourth byte.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length, as specified in the third and fourth byte is little-endian, whereas it should be big-endian. The correct frame is `'\x81\x7e\x00\xd0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklm nopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNO PQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`